# Is it safe to set password field as attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, mass-assignment

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

If not, can you please give example of method which prevents 'undefined' error when attr_accessible is removed.

Comment: why would you need to get password, ever?

Comment: ? because when user authenticates, from controller I check if input equal password in DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe. Attr_accessible is only dangerous for attributes that control your application logic. For example, if you have a flag that says "yes I've checked this user is an admin", and it can be set by the user instead, because it's attr_accessible, then it's a vulnerability.

Since the password is a piece of information that is provided by the user anyway, making it settable by the same user does not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you are security paranoid, you could do this is defining the method password:

```
def password
  self.password
end
```

this way the password can't be set by hand.

But you shouldn’t worry about it because many login gems like devise needs password in attr_accessible.

Comment: ha) thanks. I'm not paranoid, but as I just don't know how hacking works, I can't tell how such issues reflects on security. I just knew it is somehow connected with security)